# cx_freeze and single-file eggs

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cx-freeze, egg

I'm trying to use `cx_freeze` on Windows 7 with a python2.7 distutils script, and it seems to get tripped up on 2 packages: `rsa` & `pyasn1`:

```
error: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.7.egg\\pyasn1/*.*'
```

(the error for `rsa` is analogous.)

At first I thought this was a permissions issue (both egg files showed a padlock badge), but even after changing permissions, the error remains.

Then I noticed that these two eggs are not directories, but individual files, which would explain why cx_freeze can't find the requested subdirectory.

I have tried specifying these as either `packages` or `includes`; either way, I get the error shown.

I have also tried designating them as `excludes` and then copying the eggs in directly; this allows the `cx_freeze` script to complete, but then the executable can't find the eggs.

So my question is: how can I get my cx_freeze script to recognize these eggs?

Comment: Which version of cx_Freeze?

Comment: @fedepad : the latest; just installed it this week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to re-install the problematic packages with `zip-safe` set to `False`, forcing them to be installed as directories.